# How to get the image value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi guys i am trying to get the image value from my input using jquery but it is showing value as undefined

Here is my input

```
<input placeholder="image" class="width-dynamic proba dva" type="file" onchange="updateQuesMark(2,0,this.value,2,1,0)" name="q2[]">
```

Here is in my ajax i tried like this

```
var totalfiles = $("input[name='q2']").val();
```

When i tired like this i am getting value as undefined..
Can anyone help me where i did mistake..Tq in advance.

Comment: How is "_image_" related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parameter as `"input[name='q2[]']"`

```js
var totalfiles = $("input[name='q2[]']").val();

console.log(totalfiles);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="image" class="width-dynamic proba dva" type="file" onchange="updateQuesMark(2,0,this.value,2,1,0)" name="q2[]">
```

Comment: its working but if i have 4 images in one page..it is displaying only one

Answer (score 0):

change as `$("input[name='q2[]']")`

```js
function updateQuesMark(){
  var totalfiles = $("input[name='q2[]']").val();
  console.log(totalfiles);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="image" class="width-dynamic proba dva" type="file" onchange="updateQuesMark(2,0,this.value,2,1,0)" name="q2[]">
```

Comment: its working but if i have 4 images in one page..it is displaying only one

Comment: @user123you can get all images with their name.

Comment: but i am not getting it..i can see only one  in my console

Comment: do you want to select multiple image from 1 input?

Comment: actually i have button for upload image when ever i click on image it will create one div everytime..inside one div i can able to upload 2 images. like that in 4 divs i have 4 image uploads with same input name